# EnvDTE (T4Templates Scaffolding) - how to duplicate a file in the powershell code?

Tags: c#, powershell, visual-studio-2013, t4, scaffolding

I'm using the powershell script to run multiple scaffolders. Something like this:

```
Scaffold CustomScaffolder -Parameter "Value"
Scaffold CustomScaffolder2 -Parameter "Value"
```

In some point I open a file using this command:

```
$DTE.ExecuteCommand("File.OpenFile", "FilePathInProject.cs")
```

This makes me feel I can do anything in this ps1 file.

I want to take a png file, duplicate it (copy to the same directory and rename) and add it to the project.

I've seen this command in C# that I can't manage to use in powershell:

```
project.ProjectItems.AddFromFileCopy(fileName);
```

I can only get the project object using:

```
$Project = Get-Project "ProjectName"
```

How can I copy, paste, rename and add a file to the project?

Comment: to make sure I understand you want to take photo.png copy it to photo2.png in the same directory that photo.png resides?

Comment: Exactly. + It would be nice if the file will be added to the csproj.

Comment: could you provide an example of your csproj file

Comment: if `$Project = Get-Project "ProjectName"` works, do `Get-Member $Project` or `$Project | Get-Member` to explore the object.  

Also, if you're using Powershell 3 or later, use Intellisense in ISE to explore the methods and properties of the Project object.  You may be able to do this within Visual Studio as well, if you have PS support there.  

The C# snippet you posted looks like a .NET object call.  If you add the $ in front of project it should call those methods within PS, assuming Get-Project results in the same kind of object.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve the copying and renaming of the file

```
Get-ChildItem *.png | ForEach {Copy-Item $_ ($_.Name -replace ".png$","_2.png")}
```

This only provides a starting place for you because it will depend on where your pictures are stored, because as this stands it will duplicate every image on your system. but the principal is the cam for one folder, depending on your folder path that is.

Comment: Agree, and `move-item` can move or rename files.

Comment: I'm failing to make this work in the current project. I didn't manage to get the path of the project and suppling a relative path to the image looked at the root of the drive containing the project. How can I do this for a file in the project?

Comment: you would change `Get-ChildItem *.png` to the root of the project folder such as `get-childitem c:\folder\project1\*.png`